# Почему показывается в кодировке utf-8

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals=['Снайперки']))
async def rifle(message: types.Message):
    get_data(4)

    with open('result.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for index, i in enumerate(data):
        card = f'{hlink(i.get("name"),i.get("link"))}\n' \
                f'{hbold("Цена:")} {i.get("price")}\n' \
                f'{hbold("Скидка")} {i.get("overprice")}\n' 
       
        if index%20 ==0:
            time.sleep(4)
        await message.answer(card)
```

Вот часть кода который посылает информацию через файл json.

```
<a href="https://3d.cs.money/item/VZbVOdb">â Specialist Gloves | Fade (Field-Tested)</a>
<b>Цена:</b> 857.14
<b>Скидка</b> -12.57
```

Это отвечает телеграмм.
Я не понимаю как это исправить и какую кодировку надо тогда ставить для json файла

Comment: А причем здесь кодировка, вы не там копаете.

Comment: А тогда что это.

Comment: это обычный html

Comment: Ну это я понимаю, а как это исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hlink, hbold
....
await message.answer(card, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
```